# Managed Property and Crawled Propety Mapping in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-search

if i create a new set of site columns, i am able to see the newly created managed property and newly created crawled property,

but will the managed property(auto generated) and the crawled property associated with it will be auto mapped are do we need to map it manually?

if it is automapped then how long will it take to appear in the search results ??